# Magento community 2.1.2 schedule product csv upload from ftp

Tags: magento-community, csv, importexport, magento-2.1.2, schedule

I want to import product csv file automatically from ftp.
I am using magento community 2.1.2 edition.

There is no schedule **import/export** option available in this edition.

Please suggest me a good method of doing so.

Thanks.